# Qt QML XQuery sort by descending

Tags: xml, qt, xpath, qml, xquery

I am using Qt/Qml.
I want to sort XML record by descending order with Query. How can i write this sort query?

Here is my QML item to get list and query prop

```
 XmlListModel {
        id: xmlModel
        source: "record.xml"
        query: "/catalog/* [sort($id as item()*)]"

        XmlRole { name: "id"; query: "id/string()" }
    }
```

hypothetical Xml example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <booke >
      <id>1</id>
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </booke>
   <bookz >
      <id>2</id>
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
      <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
      of the world.</description>
   </bookz>
   <bookd >
      <id>3</id>
      <author>Corets, Eva</author>
      <title>Maeve Ascendant</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-11-17</publish_date>
      <description>After the collapse of a nanotechnology 
      society in England, the young survivors lay the 
      foundation for a new society.</description>
   </bookd>
</catalog>
```

Answer (score 0):

Normal XQuery 1 (if recollection serves me) would be along the lines of

```
for $item in catalog/*
order by xs:integer($item/id) descending
return $item
```

A `sort` function was not introduced before XQuery/XPath 3.0, I think. There you could use `sort(catalog/*, (), function($item) { -$item/id })`.

I don't know what qt supports but I would rather guess XQuery 1 than 3.